# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead error in sklearn regresion models

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I started machine learning recently and when I came across regression models I found out that to train models we use **regressor.fit** method which takes 2 argument observation and result but observation array are 2d and result array is 1D. Can anyone tell me why we don't use the same dimension array for the fit method? when I tried to fit the same dimension array it gave me an error as **class expected 2d array but 1d was given**

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("Position_Salaries.csv")
x= dataset.iloc[:,1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
print(y)
print(x)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0)
reg.fit(x,y)
```

```
 Output - 
[  45000   50000   60000   80000  110000  150000  200000  300000  500000
 1000000]

[[ 1]
 [ 2]
 [ 3]
 [ 4]
 [ 5]
 [ 6]
 [ 7]
 [ 8]
 [ 9]
 [10]]
```

Comment: Have you tried `reshape(-1,1)` on the `x` variable?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani i can extract x as 2D s well but my question is why we need different dimensions array but not same .

Comment: In the case of fitting a data to a regression model using `sklearn`, you need to pass x as a matrix whose **columns** are the features. Therefore, when you have a matrix with 7 columns it means you are going to fit the data to a model with 7 features. Note that, the number of rows should always be the same in both x and y.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani in the above example number of rows of x is 10 but number of rows of y is 1 and the model is still able to train without error ...why ??

Comment: That's why I said you need to reshape just `x` variable and not y.(I don't remember any case that I needed to reshape `y` variable). I guess that's why you will always have just one dependent variable (`y`). But you can have more than one independent variable (`x`). With that in mind, you will need to have a **Vector** for the output (`y`) and a matrix for the input (`x`)

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani oh got it sir thank you very much <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the data conform to sklearn's preferred format, try the following:

```
reg.fit(x.reshape(-1,1),y.reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: yeah it helped but in my example even if I give x and y as different dimensions output of the model is still the same ....why does it is working even if its dimensions are different?

Comment: This is the format in which sklearn's classifiers and regressors expect data. There is no fundamental requirement for this format and you could build your own custom classifiers that accept different format.